# Finding a Möbius transformation sending a set onto the open unit disk.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, mobius-transformation

Let $g : G \longrightarrow \mathbb C$ be an analytic function on a region $G.$ Let $a \in G.$ Then for any $r \gt 0$ there exists a Möbius transformation $T_r$ such that $T_r \left (\mathbb C \setminus \overline {B(-g(a),r)} \right ) = D,$ where $D$ is the open unit disk. What will happen if we further require $T(g(a)) = 0\ $?

I am thinking about the following map $$z \longmapsto \frac {r} {z + g(a)}.$$ Then clearly it's a Möbius transformation taking the desired domain into $D$ misses only the origin. Is there any way to fix this? Any help in this regard would be warmly appreciated.

Thanks for investing your valuable time in reading my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some preliminary remarks:

- The domain $G$ and the analytic function $g$ are irrelevant. With $w = g(a)$ you are looking for  a Möbius transformation $T$ which maps the exterior of the disk $B(-w, r)$ onto the unit disk, with $T(w) = 0$.
- Möbius transformations map disk on the *extended complex plane* $\hat{\Bbb C} = \Bbb C \cup \{ \infty \}$ to disks or lines on the extended complex plane. $\mathbb C \setminus \overline {B(-w,r)} $ cannot be mapped to  the full unit disk, the point $T(\infty)$ will always be missing in the image.
- $T(-w) = 0$ is only possible if $w$ lies in the exterior of $B(-w, r)$, i.e. if $2|w| > r$.

So we can formulate the problem as follows: Given $w \in \Bbb C$ and $r > 0$ with $2|w| > r$, find a Möbius transformation $T$ such that $T \left (\hat{\Bbb C} \setminus \overline {B(-w,r)} \right ) = \Bbb D$ and $T(w) = 0$.

One can start as you did: $T_1(z) = r/(z+w)$ maps $\hat{\Bbb C} \setminus \overline {B(-w,r)} $ onto the unit disk, with $T_1(w) = r/(2w) =: \alpha$. The choose $T_2$ as an automorphism of the unit disk with $T_2(\alpha) = 0$. These automorphism are well-known:
$$
 T_2(z) = c\frac{z-\alpha}{1-\overline{\alpha} z} 
$$
with an arbitrary factor $c$ of modulus one. Then the composition $T = T_2 \circ T_1$ solves the given problem.

Another option to get the same result is to determine the reflection  point $w^*$ of $w$ with respect to the disk $B(-w, r)$. Since Möbius transformations preserve symmetry with respect to a circle or line, $T(w) = 0$ implies $T(w^*) = \infty$. The transformation is therefore of the form
$$
 T(z) = d \frac{z-w}{z-w^*}
$$
for some constant $d$ of modulus one. The reflection $w^*$ point of $w$ with respect to a circle $B(z_0, r)$ is determined by the formula
$$
 (w^* - z_0)\overline{(w-z_0)} = r^2 \, ,
$$
see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/923384/42969). In our case that gives $w^* = -w+ r^2/(2\bar w)$.

Comment: What do you mean by reflection of a point with respect to a disk? Why does Möbius transformation sends the point of reflection to $\infty$ if the original point goes to $0\ $?

Comment: @AntonioClaire: Look up “circle inversion” and have a look at the provided link. The reflection point of $0$ with respect to the unit circle is $\infty$, therefore $w$ and $w^*$ are mapped to $0$ and $\infty$. – If you are not comfortable with that approach then can ignore it. The first part of the answer is already a full solution.

Comment: I have understood the first part of your answer quite clearly but don't understand the second part as I am not aware of "circle inversion." I will read the thing first and then I will try to understand your answer. If I still have some doubt then I will ask. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I have two more questions in this regard. First one is why does Möbius transformation preserve symmetry with respect to a circle or a line? Second one is why does such a $T$ you mentioned will work? How do we guarantee that $|z - w| \lt |z - w^*|\ $?

Comment: @AntonioClaire: The symmetry principle is very nicely explained in “Complex Analysis” textbook by Lars Ahlfors (which everybody working in this field *must* have read :). I am still looking for a good Q&A on this site which can be used a reference for this topic. There is for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/845222/42969. I will let you know if I find a better one.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am currently a second year masters student in pure mathematics and I am willing to do research in functional analysis and operator theory. I have found many applications of complex analysis in those subjects e.g. many important results like CIT or equivalence between analyticity and smoothness continues to hold for $A$- valued holomorphic maps where $A$ is a Banach algebra. I have also some familiarity with matrix analysis. There I also found some interesting applications. That's why I am trying to understand those concepts well.

Comment: This may be of some help to understand the concept of symmetry: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3541267/42969.